# Multiple messages from Lambda to SQS using Destination trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Can I write multiple messages from Lambda to SQS using destination triggers?

My use case is,
I have to read an s3 file and add rows to SQS queue which will be further processed by another lambda function. S3 file is huge so I can't process everything using a single lambda function.

Comment: Should be doable. How many rows at once do you plan on submitting? There are limits on how much inflight messages there can be in one sqs.

Comment: Doable using destination triggers? I can batch so that I'm not going over inflight limit.

Comment: By destination triggers you mean "S3 notifications"? If yes, then the notification triggers only for the entire file, not for each individual row of data.

Comment: No, from Lambda to SQS using this: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-destinations-for-asynchronous-invocations/

Comment: Yes. Just need to be aware of the fact that SQS does not guarantee order of the messages nor uniqueness. Thus your destination functions may get duplicate copies of some rows, and in different order then originally sent.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can add multiple messages to SQS from lambda?

Comment: For function in python using boto3 you would use [send_message_batch](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message_batch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly write multiple messages from single lambda to SQS using destination functions. I ended up writing the messages from lambda-1 to SQS and using another lambda-2 to do row level processing